# Thread in android(on starting an activity)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This code runs well with no crashes but when I start a new Activity, The MainAvtivity Crashes with no details in logcat just prints (Application Terminated):

```
Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                InitializeSQLCipher();
            }
        }
    };
    t2.start();

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Info_Activity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and the InitializeSQLCipher method:

```
private void InitializeSQLCipher() {

    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(MainActivity.this);

    try {
        desPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/ir.plant.vision2";
        file = new File(desPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
            copyDB(MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("data"), new FileOutputStream(desPath + "/data"));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the `InitializeSQLCipher` method

Comment: Please post the `logcat error`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are finishing MainActivity while operations which are utilizing `MainActivity.this` are still going on.

Make sure that either Button on click won't get called before the completion of `InitializeSQLCipher` or onClick just wait for the operation to complete by introduction some boolean variable or you can combination of Object.wait and Object.notify